# How use property fitInto from paper-dialog

Tags: html, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

Hello im new on polymer and im tried to fit my dialog on div because i need customize that dialog like a popover.

Well i tried do this:

```
<paper-dialog fitInto="{{body}}">
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <paper-dialog-scrollable>
        Lorem ipsum...
    </paper-dialog-scrollable>
    <div class="buttons">
        <paper-button dialog-dismiss>Cancel</paper-button>
        <paper-button dialog-confirm>Accept</paper-button>
    </div>
</paper-dialog>
```

but not result, Thanks btw

Answer (score 2):

CamelCase properties translate to dashed (-) attributes. So use `fit-into` instead.

Comment: Ok this works. But what is the correct syntax because he always append dialog-modal to <body>. And throws me this error : TypeError: this.fitInto.getBoundingClientRect is not a function

Comment: You need to pass in Object that is a DOM element. Passing a selector won't work. I can't find a good example in the documentation for this.

Answer (score 0):

THanks to all.

I solved like maria says, passing one DOM element on javascript.

```
$("paper-dialog")[0].fitInto = $("#contentInputsNav")[0]
```